# Make check fails pintos test cases

Tags: ubuntu, qemu, pintos

So I'm very new to Ubuntu and PintOS as well. Our first assignment was to install PintOS  on qemu and make a few changes to some files to execute them.
However, make check is giving me these errors on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

```
~/pintos/src/threads$ make check
cd build && make check
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/asadn/pintos/src/threads/build'
pintos -v -k -T 60 --qemu  -- -q  run alarm-single < /dev/null 2> tests/threads/alarm-single.errors > tests/threads/alarm-single.output
perl -I../.. ../../tests/threads/alarm-single.ck tests/threads/alarm-single tests/threads/alarm-single.result
FAIL tests/threads/alarm-single
run: TIMEOUT after 61 seconds of wall-clock time - load average: 0.29, 0.41, 0.50
pintos -v -k -T 60 --qemu  -- -q  run alarm-multiple < /dev/null 2> tests/threads/alarm-multiple.errors > tests/threads/alarm-multiple.output
perl -I../.. ../../tests/threads/alarm-multiple.ck tests/threads/alarm-multiple tests/threads/alarm-multiple.result
FAIL tests/threads/alarm-multiple
run: TIMEOUT after 61 seconds of wall-clock time - load average: 0.62, 0.48, 0.52
pintos -v -k -T 60 --qemu  -- -q  run alarm-simultaneous < /dev/null 2> tests/threads/alarm-simultaneous.errors > tests/threads/alarm-simultaneous.output
perl -I../.. ../../tests/threads/alarm-simultaneous.ck tests/threads/alarm-simultaneous tests/threads/alarm-simultaneous.result
FAIL tests/threads/alarm-simultaneous
run: TIMEOUT after 61 seconds of wall-clock time - load average: 0.60, 0.48, 0.52
pintos -v -k -T 60 --qemu  -- -q  run alarm-priority < /dev/null 2> tests/threads/alarm-priority.errors > tests/threads/alarm-priority.output
perl -I../.. ../../tests/threads/alarm-priority.ck tests/threads/alarm-priority tests/threads/alarm-priority.result
FAIL tests/threads/alarm-priority
run: TIMEOUT after 61 seconds of wall-clock time - load average: 0.77, 0.55, 0.54
pintos -v -k -T 60 --qemu  -- -q  run alarm-zero < /dev/null 2> tests/threads/alarm-zero.errors > tests/threads/alarm-zero.output
perl -I../.. ../../tests/threads/alarm-zero.ck tests/threads/alarm-zero tests/threads/alarm-zero.result
FAIL tests/threads/alarm-zero
run: TIMEOUT after 61 seconds of wall-clock time - load average: 0.53, 0.52, 0.53
pintos -v -k -T 60 --qemu  -- -q  run alarm-negative < /dev/null 2> tests/threads/alarm-negative.errors > tests/threads/alarm-negative.output
perl -I../.. ../../tests/threads/alarm-negative.ck tests/threads/alarm-negative tests/threads/alarm-negative.result
FAIL tests/threads/alarm-negative
run: TIMEOUT after 61 seconds of wall-clock time - load average: 0.54, 0.51, 0.53
pintos -v -k -T 60 --qemu  -- -q  run priority-change < /dev/null 2> tests/threads/priority-change.errors > tests/threads/priority-change.output
perl -I../.. ../../tests/threads/priority-change.ck tests/threads/priority-change tests/threads/priority-change.result
FAIL tests/threads/priority-change
run: TIMEOUT after 61 seconds of wall-clock time - load average: 0.44, 0.49, 0.52
pintos -v -k -T 60 --qemu  -- -q  run priority-donate-one < /dev/null 2> tests/threads/priority-donate-one.errors > tests/threads/priority-donate-one.output
perl -I../.. ../../tests/threads/priority-donate-one.ck tests/threads/priority-donate-one tests/threads/priority-donate-one.result
FAIL tests/threads/priority-donate-one
run: TIMEOUT after 61 seconds of wall-clock time - load average: 0.41, 0.47, 0.51
pintos -v -k -T 60 --qemu  -- -q  run priority-donate-multiple < /dev/null 2> tests/threads/priority-donate-multiple.errors > tests/threads/priority-donate-multiple.output
^[[1;2A^[[1;2A^[[1;2Bperl -I../.. ../../tests/threads/priority-donate-multiple.ck tests/threads/priority-donate-multiple tests/threads/priority-donate-multiple.result
FAIL tests/threads/priority-donate-multiple
run: TIMEOUT after 61 seconds of wall-clock time - load average: 0.41, 0.47, 0.51
pintos -v -k -T 60 --qemu  -- -q  run priority-donate-multiple2 < /dev/null 2> tests/threads/priority-donate-multiple2.errors > tests/threads/priority-donate-multiple2.output
```

There is no error when my friend uses it on Ubuntu 14.04. Can i get any suggestions so i can run it on 16.04 LTS instead of installing an older release of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

You might not have re-enabled interrupts after you've disabled them.

Answer (score 0):

Use gcc-4.1.2 to recompile pintos source files